# Use arbitrary OpenID provider in flutter supabase

Tags: flutter, authentication, openid-connect, supabase, supabase-flutter

I am using supabase and flutter and I need to implement SSO with an OpenID (OIDC) provider that is not supported out of the box from supabase. As Facebook and some other standard providers use OIDC under the hood, I expect it should be possible. But in the UI I can only see SAML 2.0 but no OIDC.

I found [this](https://github.com/orgs/supabase/discussions/6547) communtiy question. But also this [issue](https://github.com/supabase/gotrue/issues/159) which was closed after merging a [PR](https://github.com/supabase/gotrue-js/pull/207). But even with this issue closed I am not sure how to implement it in flutter. I couldn't find any example code whatsoever. Could anyone guide me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Arbitrary OpenID support is not yet supported on Supabase, but it is in the road map.

Comment: @dshukertjr :| damn. Is there more information on when this is planned to be supported?

Comment: Nothing set in stone at the moment.